# How to merge two unix txt files

Tags: shell, unix

I have file1 which has data as follows:

```
url1
url2
url3
url4
.
.
.
```

file2 has data as below:

```
xml1
xml2 
xml3
.
.
.
```

I want to merge these two files and the merged file say file3 should look below:

```
url1
xml1
url2
xml2
url3
xml3
url4
xml4
```

Comment: Is this the real data? Could you please add an example of the real data? Are these strings always separated by a whitespace?

Comment: While you're editing your question with real data, please also indicate if you expect there will there always be an xml{n} for each url{n}? Good luck.

Comment: they are some http url's always in both the files.. like http://google.com/ab/bc                                                                             http://google.com/cd/de

Comment: file1:

http://google.com/studio/image
http://google.com/studio/image1


file2:
http://yahoo.com/standard/img
http://yahoo.com/standard/img1

merged file say file3 should be

http://google.com/studio/image
http://yahoo.com/standard/img
http://google.com/studio/image1
http://yahoo.com/standard/img1

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26601/how-to-read-from-two-input-files-using-while-loop

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
while read -r file1 && read -r file2 <&3; do
  echo "$file1"; echo "$file2"
done <file1.txt 3<file2.txt
```